# Why are the coefficients of the modular equation so large?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

The modular equation $\Phi_n(X,Y)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbf Z[X,Y]$ relating the modular invariant $j$ and the functions 
$j\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right)$, where $ad-bc=n$.

For example, we have identically

$$\Phi_n(j(n\tau),j(\tau))=0.$$

It is often asserted that the coefficients of $\Phi_n(X,Y)$ are *astronomically* large even for small values of $n$. Why is this so? Is there some lower bound on the coefficients?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Paula Cohen, [On the coefficients of the transformation polynomials for the elliptic modular
function,](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-the-coefficients-of-the-transformation-polynomials-for-the-elliptic-modular-function/6D1315068F3E83B031CBBBCE853AAD9C) Math. Proc. of the Cambridge Phil. Soc. **95**, 389–402 (1984).

The largest coefficient $c_{m}$ in absolute value of $\Phi_{m}$ is of order
$$c_{m}\simeq m^{km},$$
with $k$ a number of order unity ($k=9$ for $m=2^n$). So for $m=2^{10}=1024$ one has $c_m\simeq 10^{27743}$ --- astronomically large, indeed.